# Find $x,~y;~z\in (0;1)$ witch satisfy equation

Tags: calculus

Find  $x,~y;~z\in (0;1)$, such that:

$$(x+\frac{1}{2x}-1)(y+\frac{1}{2y}-1)(z+\frac{1}{2z}-1)=(1-\frac{xy}{z})(1-\frac{yz}{x})(1-\frac{zx}{y})$$

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 m = \left( {x + \frac{1}{{2x}} - 1} \right)\left( {y + \frac{1}{{2y}} - 1} \right)\left( {z + \frac{1}{{2z}} - 1} \right) \\ 
  \Leftrightarrow m = \frac{{2x^2  - 2x + 1}}{{2x}} \times \frac{{2y^2  - 2y + 1}}{{2y}} \times \frac{{2z^2  - 2z + 1}}{{2z}} \\ 
  \Leftrightarrow m = \frac{{(2x^2 -2x +1)(2y^2 -2y +1)(2z^2 -2z +1)}}{8xyz}\\ 
 k = \left( {1 - \frac{{yz}}{x}} \right)\left( {1 - \frac{{xz}}{y}} \right)\left( {1 - \frac{{xy}}{z}} \right) \\ 
  \Leftrightarrow k = \frac{1}{{xyz}}\left( {x - yz} \right)\left( {y - xz} \right)\left( {z - xy} \right) \\ 
m =k \Leftrightarrow 2^3 \left( {x - yz} \right)\left( {y - xz} \right)\left( {z - xy} \right) = (2x^2 -2x +1)(2y^2 -2y +1)(2z^2 -2z +1) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

Comment: think you  Tacet